# WCF with SSL hosted by iis 7.5 or consolehost

Tags: wcf, iis, ssl, console

this is a very straightforward and easy question.
So please give me an easy answer(tutorial would be good)..
And not a very difficult expert anwswer(what I all the time find on google..)

So the question is:
1. How do you create a simple webservice that will be hosted by iis 7.5 and has SSL

1. How do you create a simple webservice that will be hosted by console and has SSL
2. If you create a client that use a SSL wcf host then you first need to select Yes or No, how can the computer automatically select YES?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To configure IIS hosted WCF service work with SSL you need:
1. Install Certificate
2. Set SSL is required in your application settings in inetmgr.
3. Configure security in WCF service settings. Here is an example of security settings of WCF service

```
  ...
  <service behaviorConfiguration="YourServiceBehavior" name="...">
  ...
 <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="YourServiceBehavior">
      ...
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="CerttificateName" storeLocation="CertificateStoreLocation"
          storeName="CertificateStoreName" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      ...
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
...
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="YourBindingName" ...>
    ...
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
...
```

I don't have an answer for you about console hosted WCF service and SSL.
Also I'm not sure what do you mean when asking how can the computer automatically select yes. It seems you are talking about accept using of certificate considered as not valid. Line of code below should help to do that.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
```